# Modal Function Button Onclick

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, bootstrap-modal

I have created a Modal on a Create View. I have three buttons - '*Add Conditions', 'No Conditions',* and *'Cancel'*. When clicking each button I would like it to perform an action. So far the only button that works is the 'Cancel' button as I am using `data-dismiss="modal"` and not code in my controller. My question is how do you access a `ActionResult` in your controller. I have tried the following Modal code and corresponding Ajax code.

Modal:

```
<button type="button" id="confirmItem" data-target="#confirmModal" data-toggle="modal" @*data-id="#AddConditions">Create</button>


<body>
<br/>
     <div class="modal fade" id="confirmModal" tabindex="-1" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
         <div class="modal-dialog">
             <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dissmiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">@*&times;*@</button>
                          <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm</h4>
                </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Confirm that Requested Burn Conditions should be added.</p>
             </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="btnAddConditions" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add Conditions</button>
                <button id="btnNoConditions" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >No Conditions</button>
                <button data-dismiss="modal" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var checkConditon;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".confirmItem").click(function (e) {

        checkConditon = $(this).data('id');
        alert("confirm item " + $(this).data('id'));
    });
    $('#btnAddConditions').click(function () {
        alert("add condition " + $(this).data('id'));
        window.location = "/RequestedBurns/AddCondition/" + checkConditon;
    });
    $('#btnNoConditions').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "Create",
             success: function (){
                 alert("success")
             },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("Error Ajax not working: " + error);
            }
        });
     });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

tried below code to call controller actions from ajax in MVC.

```
 var checkConditon = $(".confirmItem").data('id');
 var url = '@Url.Action("AddCondition", "RequestedBurns")';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: { checkConditon : checkConditon }, 
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert("Error Ajax not working: " + error);
        }
    });
```